# Stateprovider configuration with external json file

Tags: javascript, angularjs, json

I'm working with angular.js and `$stateProvider`. I would like to use something like states.json to manage all the states, instead of write them one by one, like I'm doing now:

```
function configState($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider, $compileProvider) {

    function resolveUrl(path){
        var loadUrl = { 
            loadModule: ['$ocLazyLoad', function($ocLazyLoad) {               
                return $ocLazyLoad.load(path);
            }]
        };
        return loadUrl;
    }

    $compileProvider.debugInfoEnabled(true);

    // Set default state
    $urlRouterProvider.otherwise("/dashboard");
    $stateProvider

    // Dashboard - Main page
    .state('dashboard', {
        url: "/dashboard",
        templateUrl: "views/dashboard.html",
        data: {
            pageTitle: 'Dashboard',
        }
    })
    .state('reports', {
        url: "/reports",
        templateUrl: "views/reports.html",
        data: {
            pageTitle: 'Reports',
        }
    })
    .state('invoices', {
      url: "/invoices",
      controller: 'invoicesCtrl',
      templateUrl: '/invoices/views/invoices.html',
      resolve: resolveUrl('/invoices/app/js/compiled/invoices_app.js')
    })
    .state('invoices.upload', {
        url: "/upload",
        controller: 'invoicesCtrl',
        templateUrl: '/invoices/views/invoices.html',
        resolve: resolveUrl('/invoices/app/js/compiled/invoices_app.js')
    })
    .state('users', {
        url: "/users",
        controller: 'usersCtrl',
        templateUrl: '/users/views/users.html',
        resolve: resolveUrl('/users/app/js/compiled/users_app.js')
    });
}

angular
    .module('homer')
    .config(configState)
    .run(function($rootScope, $state) {
        $rootScope.$state = $state;
    });
```

Is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your.json file follows this structure:

```
{
    "invoices": {
        "name": "invoices",
        "url": "/invoices",
        "controller": "invoicesCtrl",
        "templateUrl": "./invoices.html"
    },
    "reports": {
        "name": "reports",
        "url": "/reports",
        "controller": "reportsCtrl",
        "templateUrl": "./reports.html"
    },
}
```

Cycle through them all in a `for in` loop inside the .config method argument function

```
for(var prop in states){
    $stateProvider.state(prop, states[prop])
}
```

PS: I don't think you can embed js functions like `resolveUrl` in json objects